# Weakly star compact set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

a) Show that if $E\subset N^{*}$ is weakly* closed and bounded in norm of $N^{*}$ then $E$ is weakly star compact

b) Show that in a Banach space $B $ a subset $E\subset B^{*} $is weakly compact if and only if $E$ is closed in the weak topology* and bounded (in the norm of $N*$)

I don't have clear the equivalence or definition of weakly* compact, so i used the next definition:

the set $E$ is weakly * closed if every sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ has a weakly star convergent subsquence $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$ i.e for each $x \in N$
$$f_{n_{k}}(x) \to f(x)$$, but i dont know what to do with this. For hypotesis $E $ is bounded, so  $\{f_{n}\}$  is bounded, i think that i can uses this for something but i'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Sequences are not enough to characterize weak* compact sets, you must use nets: In order to verify that $E\subset B^*$ is weak* compact, you need to check that every net in $E$ has a weak* convergent subnet.  The situation is much simpler when $B$ is separable, as then the weak* topology restricted to bounded subsets of $B^*$ is metrizable. This implies that if $E$ is bounded, it suffices to check that every sequence in $E$ has a weak* convergent subsequence.

For a) you can use Alaoglu's theorem, which states that the closed unit ball of $B^*$, that is, $ball(B^*)=\{f \in B^* \colon \|f\| \le 1\}$, is weak* compact.

I don't think b) is correct the way you stated it: $ball(B^*)$ is   weak* closed and bounded  but not weakly compact, unless $B^*$  is reflexive. So it is not true that $E \subset B^*$ is weakly compact $\iff$ $E$ is weak* closed and bounded.

What I think you meant for b) is that $E \subset B^*$ is weak* compact $\iff$ $E$ is weak* closed and bounded. One direction comes from a) and the other one is a classic application of the Uniform Boundedness Principle.